# jQuery tabs will not hold my php in it

Tags: php, jquery, html, tabs

I cannot quite figure out what is wrong within my code but for some odd reason I had the PHP code entered into tab 2 but then it escaped that tab and entered all of the other ones. So it is visible in that tab aswell as the other tabs i have. 
This PHP code is to retreive icons and folders.

I had trouble putting the code in here so here it is:

http://pastebin.com/egD4Lbc9

This happens in the div called 'fragment 2'

Comment: Without all the resources, it is not possibel to execute. BTW, you are missing a closing `DIV`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have only 2  li for fragment 1 and fragment 3?

```
 <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
```

Try to add 2nd tab? at least hidden